# SharePoint 2010 SP1 install failure

Tags: 2010

I apparently have a SharePoint version problem on a farm that I've been managing for a few month.

In the central admin, version indicates that I do have SP1 installed.
But when I run the PowerShell command : get-spfarm | select BuildVersion the version is the RTM version ...

In the CA I went to the "check upgrade status", and I found issues that happened in 2011, but the logs are not there anymore, so I don't know what went wrong.

This is production farm, and the preproduction one has SP1 installed correctly
I'd like to deploy SP2 on these farms. I was thinking I should probably do the following:

- try to install SP1 again on the production, to be in the same state as preproduction before deploying SP2
- Working installation or not, deploy SP2 on preproduction, and then on production

I figure even if SP1 doesn't work, SP2 might have a chance to work right ? Or would you do it another way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have the proper backup / restore strategy in place . Run the Sharepoint Configuration Wizard again and see if it runs through the entire steps. At that time it would generate a log file where you can figure it out if there are any issues. After that you can install SP2

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, the thing is we have to go through a (long) validation process before I can do it ...

Comment: Running a SharePoint Configuration wizard seems to be scary . I had to run it again recently and I was doing it for the first time . Make sure you validate your backup restore process that's the only thing

Answer (score 0):

Did you also run the psconfig?

```
CD "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Bin\"
PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

I've noticed that for both SP1 and SP2, I had to run the psconfig twice. The first time it returns "failed", and the second time, it returns "success" and everything works just fine thereafter.